# Algolia - Wordpress - exclude certain pages from index

Tags: wordpress, algolia

Currently I am indexing all pages of wordpress in Algolia.

What would be the best way to exclude certain pages from being indexed at Algolia? There should be around 20 pages that need to be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following to exclude certain posts by ID:

```
/**
 * @param bool    $flag
 * @param WP_Post $post
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function custom_should_index_post( $flag, WP_Post $post ) {

    // TODO: Replace with your own post IDs to exclude. 
    $excluded_ids = array( 20, 25 );
    if ( in_array( $post->ID, $excluded_ids ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $flag;
}

add_filter( 'algolia_should_index_post', 'custom_should_index_post', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'algolia_should_index_searchable_post', 'custom_should_index_post', 10, 2 );
```

Of course you could also base your decision on any other value like the post type or a custom attribute.